# Instance variables in Lisp?

Tags: lisp, clisp

I'm writing a function for a CLOS class that reverses the list element of an object of said class.

I have a method that will return the reverse list, but how do I make it set the object's list to that list? Can I have a instance variable in the function that stores the list then set the element to that? Or is there an easier way?

Here's the method as it is now:

```
(defun my-reverse (lst)
    (cond ((null lst) ‘())
           (t (append (my-reverse (cdr lst)) (car lst)))))
```

The object it is passed is (l my-list) and the accessor would then be (my-list-ls l).

Edit: Realized that `cons` doesn't work on 2 lists.

Edit2: What I assume the right code would be:

```
(defun my-reverse (l my-list)
        (cond ((null (my-list-ls l) ‘())
               (t (setf (my-list-ls l) (append (my-reverse (cdr (my-list-ls l)))
                                         (car (my-list-ls l)))))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to modify an object's slot, you need to pass that object itself to your function, not just the value of the slot you want to change.

EDIT: regarding the edit2 of the question

I assume `my-list` is the name of the class, and you don't actually want to pass it to  the function, right? In that case, you should substitute the `defun` with a `defmethod`. Also, it should be better to change the instance only once, after you reversed the whole list, instead of at each step. You could use an inner function for that:

```
(defmethod my-reverse ((l my-list))
  (labels ((inner (list acc)
             (if (endp list)
                 acc
                 (inner (rest list) (cons (first list) acc)))))
     (setf (my-list-ls l) (inner (my-list-ls l) ()))))
```

EDIT 2: detailed explanation

`defmethod` is the alternative to `defun` for defining (polymorphic) methods. Though, if you don't need polymorphism, you could just use `(defun my-reverse (l)` for the first line.

`labels` is for inner function definitions. Here, it defines an inner function named `inner` with the two parameters `list` and `acc`. `inner` is the function that does the actual reversing, and it's a tail-recursive function because reversing goes naturally with tail-recursion. (It can build its result with `cons` and is therefore of linear complexity, whereas your solution needs `append` and thereby is of quadratic complexity, because `cons` itself is constant, but `append` is linear.)

`first` and `rest` are just alternate names for `car` and `cdr`, `endp` is mostly just an alternate name for `null`, with the difference that `endp` will signal an error if its argument isn't actually a list.

Finally, the last line calls `inner` with the original and an empty list as arguments, and assigns the result to the slot (aka instance variable).

Comment: That's what I'm doing by making the parameter (l my-list) The example code is for doing it with any list, my issue is making the function save the result in the list element of my-list l.

Comment: The function in your current example code is receiving a list, not a CLOS object. Either you're mistaken about what you're doing, or your example code isn't relevant to your question at all. Generally speaking about your question, each accessor function that is a writer is a SETF-able place. If there is no such accessor, `(slot-value slot)` is also a SETF-able place.

Comment: You guys didn't get what I'm asking, whatever, I put what I guess would be the right modification of the code underneath.

Comment: The new example helped me guess what you actually want, I think. The edit to my answer should be a working version. Please ask if you don't get how it works.

Comment: Basically most of what you added. >_< At least I know what list does, but I can't find the other parts in the slides anywhere, the slides have always been enough for the last assignment.

Comment: `list` isn't actually used as a function at all in my definition, I use it just as a parameter name. I've added a detailed explanation to my answer. Another thing: you're mentioning now that this is a homework assignment. You should have added the appropriate tag to the question in that case. (I've don that now.) I suppose you'll have to modify my code to use only those language features that have been introduced to you yet.

Comment: Well since inner was never introduced I would have to implement a helper function. But you know what, I don't care. :P Everything else in there was taught, I was just confused about everything with inner, I was thinking I was going to have to make a helper function to call in there but it's good to know about that. After this class I definitely want to use LISP more. :D (and Ruby, but not Prolog, this is a class about the different programming paradigms)

Comment: Shouldn't the second element passed to inner be `() not ()?

Comment: As a side note I'm always confused between using ` and '

Comment: The empty list doesn't need to be quoted, though a quote will also do no harm.